# Jcrop image inside Bootstrap 3 Modal not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jcrop

I'm manipulating Jcrop plugin to work inside a bootstrap 3 modal.

Unfortunately, I cant seem to figure out why my output doesn't show the image inside the modal not until you click the **CROP Buttons** inside the modal.

here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input id="file" type="file" name="upload">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info fileinput-exists" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".edit-modal-sm">Edit</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade edit-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Picture</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button id="cropbutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Crop</button>
        <button id="rotatebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Rotate</button>
        <button id="hflipbutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">H-flip</button>
        <button id="vflipbutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">V-flip</button>
        <br>
        <div id="views"></div>
        <h2>Submit form</h2>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload form data and image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var crop_max_width = 400;
var crop_max_height = 400;
var jcrop_api;
var canvas;
var context;
var image;

var prefsize;

$("#file").change(function() {
  loadImage(this);
});

function loadImage(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    canvas = null;
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      image = new Image();
      image.onload = validateImage;
      image.src = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
  var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
  if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
    var parts = dataURL.split(',');
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);

    return new Blob([raw], {
      type: contentType
    });
  }
  var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
  var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
  var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
  var rawLength = raw.length;
  var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);
  for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
    uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new Blob([uInt8Array], {
    type: contentType
  });
}

function validateImage() {
  if (canvas != null) {
    image = new Image();
    image.onload = restartJcrop;
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  } else restartJcrop();
}

function restartJcrop() {
  if (jcrop_api != null) {
    jcrop_api.destroy();
  }
  $("#views").empty();
  $("#views").append("<canvas id=\"canvas\">");
  canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  $("#canvas").Jcrop({
    onSelect: selectcanvas,
    onRelease: clearcanvas,
    boxWidth: crop_max_width,
    boxHeight: crop_max_height
  }, function() {
    jcrop_api = this;
  });
  clearcanvas();
}

function clearcanvas() {
  prefsize = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: canvas.width,
    h: canvas.height,
  };
}

function selectcanvas(coords) {
  prefsize = {
    x: Math.round(coords.x),
    y: Math.round(coords.y),
    w: Math.round(coords.w),
    h: Math.round(coords.h)
  };
}

function applyCrop() {
  canvas.width = prefsize.w;
  canvas.height = prefsize.h;
  context.drawImage(image, prefsize.x, prefsize.y, prefsize.w, prefsize.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  validateImage();
}

function applyRotate() {
  canvas.width = image.height;
  canvas.height = image.width;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.translate(image.height / 2, image.width / 2);
  context.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
  context.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
  validateImage();
}

function applyHflip() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.translate(image.width, 0);
  context.scale(-1, 1);
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  validateImage();
}

function applyVflip() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.translate(0, image.height);
  context.scale(1, -1);
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  validateImage();
}

$("#cropbutton").click(function(e) {
  applyCrop();
});
$("#rotatebutton").click(function(e) {
  applyRotate();
});
$("#hflipbutton").click(function(e) {
  applyHflip();
});
$("#vflipbutton").click(function(e) {
  applyVflip();
});

$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  var blob = dataURLtoBlob(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
  //---Add file blob to the form data
  formData.append("cropped_image[]", blob);
  $.ajax({
    url: "whatever.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("Error");
    },
    complete: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

here is my working fiddle

> https://jsfiddle.net/terenceting/v52vg3yt/1/

and another issue that i encounter is the image overflows outside the modal when the image is bigger than the modal.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Both crops work the same for me in safari?

Comment: @MarkRedman Let me update the fiddle.

Comment: @MarkRedman I've already updated the fiddle. sorry bout that.